# Linking MASM Objects with C objects gives wrong results

Tags: c, assembly, linker, masm

I have implemented a simple macro"intadd" in assembly that adds two integers (QWORDs). The driver code in C also uses QWORDS, which are a typedef for uint32_t from stdint.h. The output is always 7, regardless of the arguments.

asm.asm

```
intadd PROC x:DWORD, y:DWORD
mov eax, x
add eax, y
ret
intadd ENDP
END
```

I also tried to move y to ebx and then add eax, ebx but that produces the same results.

C-Snippet

```
extern DWORD intadd(DWORD x, DWORD y);
printf("%i", intadd(1,1));
```

Do I need to set a carry flag or something? I link the files with

```
ml64 asm.asm /c && cl.exe cfile.c /EHsc /c &&
link asm.obj cfile.obj /out:exe.exe
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about stepping through your code in a debugger (in Visual Studio or WinDbg or another)? Also, how does `printf("%i", 1+1);` relate to anything else in your question? It should just print 2.

Comment: `ml64` is the 64bit assembler. Are you using 64 bit? Make sure your assembler generates proper code for that. Better yet, just write it yourself. Try `mov eax, ecx; add eax, edx; ret`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PROC` directive searches the stack for arguments even when using ML64.exe. But the ["Microsoft x64 calling convention"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) passes arguments in registers. You can save the registers in the procedure on the so-called shadow space or - better - work directly with the registers:

```
intadd PROC
    mov eax, ecx
    add eax, edx
    ret
intadd ENDP
```

BTW: `DWORD` is equivalent to `unsigned int`. So, adapt your format string: `printf("%u", intadd(1,1));`. Or use the C type `int` in the C file.

Comment: Thank you for your post, my program is now working! In case anyone stumbles across this in the future: ecx and edx contain the arguments by the calling convention mentioned above, therefore, ecx is moved to eax, then edx is added and returned.